# The provided image file is invalid. Please check your image path again. Facebook Graph Api error

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to upload image to Facebook graph api with Http Client of Laravel. But I am getting the error mentioned before.

```
    $ad_account_id = env("AD_ACCOUNT_ID");
    $access_token = env("ACCESS_TOKEN");
    $image = $request->file('image');

    $response = Http::asForm()
        ->withHeaders(['Content-Type: multipart/form-data'])
        ->post('https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/act_' . $ad_account_id . '/adimages',
            [
                'filename' => file_get_contents($image),
                'access_token' => $access_token
            ]
        );

    dd(json_decode($response->body()));
```

In documentation Facebook gives me curl api example like this

```
curl \
  -F 'filename=@<IMAGE_PATH>' \
  -F 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v<API_VERSION>/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/adimages
```

Problem is all about IMAGE_PATH. I have tried to send any kind of path of uploaded image even in base64 format. I am able to upload the same image with same api in Postman. There is not any problem about `access_token` or `ad_account_id`.

Comment: They do not want you to send the _path_ (what would the API be supposed to do with a _local_ path value you provide?), but the actual file content. `filename=@<IMAGE_PATH>` with the `@` in there is special cURL syntax meaning "make this a file upload."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem by using `attach` method of HTTP client:

```
$ad_account_id = env("AD_ACCOUNT_ID");
$access_token = env("ACCESS_TOKEN");
$image = $request->file('image');

$response = Http::attach('filename', file_get_contents($image), 'image.jpg')
    ->post('https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/act_' . $ad_account_id . '/adimages',
        [
            'access_token' => $access_token
        ]
    );

dd(json_decode($response->body()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Will recommend to use PHP SDK for such operations.
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk

```php
    $account = new \FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount('Your ID');
    assert($account instanceof \FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount);
    $account->createAdImage(['array of fields'],['array of request Params'],);
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I know there is SDK to use but I don't want to use ready packages so much. Instead I am trying to make my own logic. If you have solution for my logic let me know.

Comment: I am not sure, but it seems access_token needs to be passed as query param. 

--> https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/me?fields&access_token=<access token sanitized> - From doc example

Comment: Thanks for saving my time Alexander. You are right that was request issue. I had to attach `filename` to my request in Http Client. `access_token` need to be passed as query param.

Comment: Glad to help you :)