# Facebook Marketing API HTTP POST error - The provided image file is invalid. Please check your image path again

Tags: post, facebook-graph-api, file-upload, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to upload an image to Facebook but am getting the error **"The provided image file is invalid. Please check your image path again."**

As a noob, I was able to create the campaigns and the ad sets (which was a huge challenge - but I am happy I did it). Unfortunately, I am stuck in the ads (ad creative).

I read many questions here and on the internet but still can't understand how to do it.

[Questions 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72868175/the-provided-image-file-is-invalid-please-check-your-image-path-again-facebook), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48505543/how-to-create-an-ad-image-with-a-fb-sandbox-account), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667797/using-curl-to-upload-post-data-with-files), and more...

According to the documentation, I first need to create an AdImage object from an image file. ([link here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis/get-started?locale=en_US#campaign))

```
  -F 'filename=@<IMAGE_PATH>' \
  -F 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v<API_VERSION>/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/adimages
```

I tried to do it with the Graph Explorer using an image file that is on my desktop, but it did not work:

```
POST to https://graph.facebook.com/v<API_VERSION>/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/adimages
{
         "filename": "@/Users/myname/Desktop/test_1.png"
}
```

***I do not understand how I can upload an image file using HTTP and I have two questions:***

**1. What am I doing wrong in the Graph Explorer? What should I change to work?**

**2. How can I download/upload an image using an HTTP POST request?**

My final goal is to have a Make scenario that will read the images from a Google Drive folder, upload them to the Facebook Media Library, and then I will create a campaign.

Make returns a lot of data from Google Drive files, such as URL, sharable link, image format, mime and many more. But I don't know how to upload it based on a URL, for example.

So, what I need is a POST request that will get the image data and upload to Facebook Media Library.

To illustrate, let's say I would have something like this - how can I make the POST request work and read/upload the image?

```
POST to https://graph.facebook.com/v<API_VERSION>/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/adimages
{
         "access_token": "<ACCESS_TOKEN>,
         "filename": "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1uQQqMhzakhKoBGcHeI6zCP_Nu"
}
```

I think that if I am able to download it from Google Drive and upload it to the Media Library to have the image hash, I will get to where I need to.